# How should I sign a Mac app for push notifications?

Tags: macos, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to develop a small enterprise tool that has push notifications. I have notifications arriving via the development certificate and development provisioning and certs, however, not in release mode.

The error I get is

`2015-07-14 15:34:32.507 My App Name[14254:2683449] application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: with error = Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1.)" (kCFHostErrorHostNotFound / kCFStreamErrorSOCKSSubDomainVersionCode / kCFStreamErrorSOCKS5BadResponseAddr / kCFStreamErrorDomainPOSIX / evtNotEnb / siInitSDTblErr / kUSBPending / dsBusError / kStatusIsError / kOTSerialSwOverRunErr / cdevResErr / EPERM:  / Error code is the version of SOCKS which the server wishes to use /  / POSIX errno; interpret using <sys/errno.h>  / event not enabled at PostEvent / slot int dispatch table could not be initialized. /  / bus error /  /  / Couldn't get a needed resource; alert / Operation not permitted)`

Should I be using a developer ID if I just want to distribute a .app file? Or can I use what I'm trying to do now and just use the a Mac Distribution provisioning profile and Mac App Distribution certificate?

Comment: Are you distributing the application outside of the App Store?

Comment: Any chance you were able to try `codesign`? Is there some reason you can't use it in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to sign the app using `codesign`

Something like `codesign --sign "Developer ID Application: MyCompany (123)" /path/to/myapp.app`